# Why does the Zend server 8 has both PHP 5.5 and 5.6?

Tags: php, zend-server

I am trying to upgrade our Zend Server 6.3 IBM i free edition and researching about the new version of Zend searver. 
Zend server 8 looks like that it already came out from the previous Beta version to now the real version. Then it has two options as PHP5.5 and PHP5.6. Why are there the two versions? Which version do we need to pick? Is it easy enough to upgrade from version 6.X to 8 if you have an experience? Is it possible to upgrade from 6.3 free edition to 8 free edition if there is a free version of 8?

Thanks,

Comment: That's a lot of questions. You might want to split those up really. In any case, go for PHP 5.6 - there's no reason to choose an older, slower version.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I mainly wanted to ask about the Free edition of version 8. Is anyone upgraded to 8 from 6.X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best is to read the manual at [the zend server docs](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend-server.htm). You can not run more then one PHP version at the same time. Hence the different versions. And I would go for PHP 5.6

Comment: okay, thank. Perhaps, no one has any experience to upgrade from 6.3 free edition to 8 free/released edition yet?

Comment: [IBMi upgrade](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/downloads#IBM%20i) should help you.